# How do I prevent an on.submit event from changing/reloading the page?

Tags: dart

In **Javascript** when I provide an `onSubmit` function, and I return 'false' from the function,  it prevents the page from changing/reloading.

However in **Dart** the `onSubmit.listen(...)` function does not take a return type.

**How do I stop the submit from sending the form data and changing/reloading the page?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the `on.submit.add(...)` callback, you will receive the `Event` as an argument. The `Event` object provides a [`preventDefault()`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/continuous/dart_html/Event.html#preventDefault) method to prevent or cancel the default action.

It can be used as follows:

```dart
querySelector('#myForm').onSubmit.listen((Event e) {
  // ... your code here
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Hi, could some please update this code to reflect the current status of dart. I tried but it does not work. I would also like the solution.

Comment: Hello Matt B. Great work brother! Your current solution works!!! It is the only one I have tried in Dart that works. Now I can use all my polymer.dart components with form elements at will. Previously it was not possible because of the default submission. Thanks again Matt B and you have a Merry Christmas.