# How do I programmatically access tooltips (title property) service in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I there some mechanism to access the HTML5 tooltip (title property) programmatically in Dart?

I would like programmatically display the tooltip if a model property falls in a certain range etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to get hold of the element and then just set the attribute.

```dart
import 'dart:html';

main(args) {
    document.querySelector('#idofyourtag').title = 'show this as tooltip';
}
```

Comment: Thanks zoechi, but how do I now activate the title on the element. I am trying to validate the content of a text element. If the validation is false, I would then set the title to the appropriate message as you indicate and then activate the tooltip. Isn't it possible to hook into HTML5 validation mechanism using Dart?

Comment: Could you solve that case already? You may programatically send the form and prevent actual sending of the form if the validation fails as show for this question [How do I prevent an on.submit event from changing/reloading the page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801516/how-do-i-prevent-an-on-submit-event-from-changing-reloading-the-page) where you recently added a comment.