# How rewrite URL?

Tags: dart

I'm making a single web app.

I have a form with a POST method and an action value equal to "/login".

```
<form action="/login" method="POST">
<label for="mail">Email</label><input name="log" id="mail" type="text">
<label for="pass">Pass</label><input name="pass" id="pass" type="text">
<input type="submit">
```

When the submit button is press, server get the form, then return to the index page.
But, in the address bar, I have "local:5050/login" and would have "local:5050".

Can I remove the "login" mention ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are making a SPA, you will not want to have the POST method of the form actually complete. Generally this is done in dart by attaching a listener on the form element, within that listener you would then do a couple of things:

1) Cancel the default action (Also see: [How do I prevent an on.submit event from changing/reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801516/how-do-i-prevent-an-on-submit-event-from-changing-reloading-the-page))

2) Get the values you're interested in from the form (or potentially take the entire form itself)

3) Send the values via an AJAX request to the server and listen for the response from the server to verify it was valid etc.

See the Dart [tutorials on forms](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/#forms) for more information on accomplishing the other steps.