# Non-triggering of onSubmit event in form

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have the following polymer dart component

```dart
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <link rel="import" href="../../../shared/ui/delete-button-form.html">

  <polymer-element name='language-combo-form'>
    <template>
      <style>
        /* author style used ie website style*/
      </style>

      <form id='form'
            name='form'
            class='form round-corners'
            on-submit='submit'>

        <input id=langTxt type='text'
               list='langs'
               value="{{lang}}"
               placeholder='English'
               required
               on-change='{{submit}}'>

       <datalist id='langs' >
          <template repeat='{{lang in langs}}'>
            <option value='{{lang}}'>{{lang}}</option>
          </template>
       </datalist>

          <button id='submit-btn' type='submit' hidden='hidden'></button>

      </form>

    </template>

     <script type="application/dart;component=1">

     import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';


      import 'package:epimss_polymer/events.dart';

      import 'dart:html';

      @CustomTag( 'language-combo-form')
      class LanguageComboForm extends PolymerElement
      {
        @observable String lang = '';

        List<String> langs = [  '', 
                                    'Basque', 'Bulgarian',
                                    'Catalan', 'Chinese - Simplified'

                                ];

        LanguageComboForm.created() : super.created();

        bool get applyAuthorStyles => true;

        void submit ( Event e, var detail, Node target )
        {
          //$['submit-btn'].click();

          $['form']
            .onSubmit
            .listen( ( Event e )
                 {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    dispatchEvent(
                              new CustomEvent( LANGUAGE_COMBO_FORM_EVENT,
                                               detail:{'lang':lang}));

                    print( 'submitted from onSubmit: $lang' );

                 });        
        }


      }

    </script>
  </polymer-element>
```

However, the code inside the submit method ...

```dart
  $['form']
            .onSubmit
            .listen( ( Event e )
                 {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    dispatchEvent(
                              new CustomEvent( LANGUAGE_COMBO_FORM_EVENT,
                                               detail:{'lang':lang}));

                    print( 'submitted from onSubmit: $lang' );

                 });
```

is Not being triggered.

If I uncomment the first line in the submit method the for is submitted as indicated by a refresh of the page but still the nothing is printed to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the method name in curly braces

```dart
  <form id='form'
        name='form'
        class='form round-corners'
        on-submit='{{submit}}'>
```

This code makes IMHO no sense (commented out lines):

```dart
// $['form'].onSubmit.listen((Event e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('submit', detail: {
    'lang': lang
  }));

  print('submitted from onSubmit: $lang');
//});
```

Why would you want to subscribe to the `submit` event inside the submit event handler?

Comment: My mistake but I had the correct thing before. Even the correction still does not print anything to the console.

Comment: I was trying to follow the example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801516/how-do-i-prevent-an-on-submit-event-from-changing-reloading-the-page. What correction is necessary Gunter?

Comment: You can either bind using the method in the linked question or bind using Polymers binding syntax. You also can use both if you think this makes sense (usually not). What you did is - using Polymer binding syntax and when the event occurs in the method that handles the event you subscribe to get notified about the event. This can't work because you are already handling this event. Remove the lines as I showed in my answer and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Dart is still a learning process for me.

Comment: The `$['form'].onSubmit.listen` would work when you add it inside `ready` or `enteredView`. The question you linked to doesn't use Polymer. In this case it is the only way to subscribe to events.

Comment: Great. I think that was my mistake - applying a non-polymer syntax to polymer.